# ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class Occasionally

Tags: android, activitynotfoundexception

I noticed few of the following error in my analytics log:

```
    content.android.ActivityNotFoundException: (Unable to find explicit activity class {com.jrea.trustapp/com.jrea.trustapp.activities.b}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?)
at app.android.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1855)
at app.android.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1546)
at app.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4298)
at b.v4.support.android.g.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
at b.v4.support.android.j.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:77)
at app.android.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4245)
at b.v4.support.android.j.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
at app.android.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4582)
at app.android.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4550)
at activities.trustapp.jrea.com.MainActivity.a(MainActivity.java:16355)
at activities.trustapp.jrea.com.MainActivity$a.onReceive(MainActivity.java:325)
at c.v4.support.android.d.a(LocalBroadcastManager.java:1297)
at c.v4.support.android.d$1.handleMessage(LocalBroadcastManager.java:116)
at os.android.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at os.android.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at app.android.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
at reflect.lang.java.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at os.internal.android.com.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

This is happening only sometimes and on some devces apparently randomly. All activities are declared in manifest, and most users don't experence issues. I tried to reproduce the error on all my devices without any success.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How starting `b` Activity ?

Comment: The answer is in stacktrace, you should declare it in manifest.xml : have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Yoleth He claims they all are: "All activities are declared in manifest". But yes i would recommend triple checking.

Comment: yes, it's declared! The strange thing is that it's happening only sometimes (only about 1% of all my users are affected).

Comment: As another side note, you can also upload the `mapping.txt` file to the playstore, along side your APK, so that such errors dont display obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks, I alrady unmapped some code part and I know who "b" activity is. It is declared in my manifest correctly, in fact I'm unable to reproduce the error.